# Assert a list containing strings with specific length

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and i want to make sure that there's no string with length > 20 , so i did the following :

```
assert not any(name for name in my_list if len(name) > 20)
```

this seems to work but when I do the following it doesn't work as expected , isn't supposed to work ?:

```
assert any(name for name in my_list if not len(name) <= 20)
```

Comment: In the 2nd case you should use `all` instead of `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is:

```
assert not any(len(name) > 20 for name in my_list)
```

This just checks each name until it finds one longer than 20 characters.

But a better way to do this is:

```
assert all(len(name) <= 20 for name in my_list)
```

This avoids the need to invert the test.

Answer (score 0):

> this seems to work but when I do the following it doesn't work as expected , isn't supposed to work ?:

No!  `if len(name) > 20` is exactly identical in functioning to `if not len(name) <= 20`.

So, effectively, the second statement is assert the inverse of the first statement. obviously, only one is going to work.

Also, what you're doing is filtering the list to see by removing elements that have length greater than 20. For inverse, you should be trying to ensure if none of the elements got filtered out -- and this might not do what you want if you're using `any(..)`

---

What you're probably looking for is:

```
assert all(len(name) <= 20 for name in my_list)  # Note that this expression is different.
```